# R Shiny : Save and load progress

Tags: r, shiny, rhandsontable

I am working on a Shiny App that uses rhandsontable and I would like to provide the user an option to save and load the progress. A minimal example of my code is as follows:

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(shiny)
library(data.table)
library(rhandsontable)
library(markdown)

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(
    menuItem("Data", tabName = "data", icon = icon("file")),
    menuItem("Control", tabName = "control", icon = icon("list-alt"))
  )
)

body <- dashboardBody(
  tabItems(
    tabItem(tabName = "data", 
            fluidRow(
              box(title = h3("Input data manually or by importing a .csv file:"),
                  #fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File:", width = '30%',
                  #    multiple = TRUE,
                  #    accept = c("text/csv",
                  #               "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                  #              ".csv")),
                  width = 12, height = 800, rHandsontableOutput("hot"))
            )
    ),
    tabItem(tabName = "control",
            fluidRow(
              actionButton("save", "Save"), actionButton("load", "Load"),
              box(title = h2("1. General Information"), width = '100%',
                  radioButtons("Type", 
                               h4("Type:"), 
                               choices = list("1" = "1", "2" = "2")),
                  radioButtons("DataExtraction", 
                               h4("Extract information:"), 
                               choices = list("Yes" = "Yes", "No" = "No"), selected = "No")
              )
            )
    )
  )
)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Shiny"),
  sidebar,
  body
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  observeEvent(input$load,{   
    values <<- readRDS("C:/Documents/ws1.RData")
    if (exists("values")) {
      lapply(names(values),
             function(x) session$sendInputMessage(x, list(value = values[[x]]))
      )
    }
  })

  observeEvent(input$save,{ 
    values <<- lapply(reactiveValuesToList(input), unclass)
    saveRDS( values , file = "C:/Documents/ws1.RData")
  })

  filedata <- reactive({
    inFile <- input$file1

    if (is.null(inFile)){
      data.table(Number1 = numeric(20),
                 Number2 = numeric(20),
                 Date1 = seq(from = Sys.Date(), by = "days", length.out = 20),
                 Date2 = seq(from = Sys.Date(), by = "days", length.out = 20))
    } else{
      fread(input$file1$datapath)
    }
  })

  output$hot = renderRHandsontable({
    rhandsontable(filedata()) %>%
      hot_cols(columnSorting = TRUE) %>%
      hot_table(highlightCol = TRUE, highlightRow = TRUE)
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I am encountering two issues:

1. When I include the fileInput("file1", ...), the inputs do not update
   anymore once I click the load action button;
2. The Rhandsontable is not updated. However, when I look into values$hot$data, it does seem as if the data is properly stored in values.

Does anyone have an idea of what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: clicking on the load button or save make the app to crash. I get this: Listening on http://127.0.0.1:4282
Warning in gzfile(file, "rb") :
  cannot open compressed file 'C:/Documents/ws1.RData', probable reason 'No such file or directory'
Warning: Error in gzfile: cannot open the connection

Comment: Hello, thanks for looking into it. I'm guessing the path C:/Documents does not exist.